# For a HTML Form, JavaScript or not? - Year 2020

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Question 1:
I am building a website form that includes more than a few input boxes (text, email, tel, URL...), a text area, and more than a few checkboxes where the user can choose more than one option.  I used all of the HTML5 validation with "required" and so on.

I am afraid of using JavaScript in forms because I read it is a doorway for hackers and HTML5 is replacing this JavaScript with its own validation attributes like "required" and more.

Is this true?

I am confused because there are tutorials that still use JavaScript for validating and sending the form information.  However, everything looks like you only need HTML for the client-side scripting.

Question 2:
Can anyone tell me what is the update with JavaScript?

Question 3:
Can we make dynamic websites with pure CSS instead of JavaScript?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is not suitable for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Your not wrong, anything clientside can be changed. You should do validation both client-side and server-side always! clientside so its not posting to your server and you already have values and state, and serverside because your right hackers dont bother decompiling and fiddling with the UI, they will target the API directly. No css cant do the validation but will be handy for displaying the errors and your form with 2020 styling and animations etc.

Comment: "Can we make dynamic websites with pure CSS instead of JavaScript?" I think it would be helpful if you could be a bit more specific about what you mean by "dynamic websites" in this context.

Comment: Question 1: HTML has a lot of concepts for validation. The short answer is: In general it should be enough for most purposes. The longer answer: If you need to support legacy browsers like Internet Explorer and use for example type="Date". It just doesnt work out of the box.

Comment: At the moment, I am only concerned with client-side scripting.  I have no issues with server-side coding.  My questions are only for the client-side.

Comment: In general, I would say that the more you're able to avoid writing JavaScript and can rely on HTML5 form validation, the better because you're leveraging code that was already well tested so there fewer chances for bugs. But that does mean you may only be getting expected validation results on later browsers, as @MatthiasGwiozda stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 have some great 'new features' which involve an attribute called `pattern` You can include regex to do some client side validation.

More about the use of pattern attribute can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

**Is HTML5 replacing javascript?**
Well not really. They both have pros and cons. Client side is always 'hackable' and if you use server side techniques to fetch the data you don't need to worry about HTML5 or Javascript being safer. Just make sure you use a SSL connect and validate/anti-SQL inject/ XSS your entries before you save them to your database.

**Can we make dynamic websites with pure CSS instead of JavaScript?**
You can style it and make it more visible to which fields are required or have an error, or make stuff visible or invisible when checking a checkbox but that's about it.

Simple example:

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="uname">Choose a username: </label>
    <input type="text" id="uname" name="name" required size="45"
           pattern="[a-z]{4,8}" title="4 to 8 lowercase letters">
    <span class="validity"></span>
    <p>Usernames must be lowercase and 4-8 characters in length.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hopefully I answered some of your questions. To be fair your stating your facts you found online, like *'I am afraid of using JavaScript in forms because I read it is a doorway for hackers and HTML5'* It would be helpful if you included that inside your question as a reference.